# How do I configure WiTopia's VPN software to be used from different user accounts on MacOSX?

Tags: osx-lion, vpn

I sent the following to WiTopia's customer support:

> I use Witopia's VPN software on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5. My wife and I
>   have different user accounts. I originally installed the Witopia
>   software FROM my account; the installer placed the executable in the
>   standard /Applications directory. When launching the Witopia
>   application from my wife's account, a dialog pops up saying that "No
>   User Data Information Found." with further instructions to redownload
>   and reinstall the software. This is unnecessary because I know the VPN
>   software works from my account. What do I need to do to enable access
>   from her account? I am very comfortable using command-line tools via
>   Terminal. I'm expecting that I need to do one of the following:
>
> - copy a set of files to a location under her account directory tree
> - modify the permissions on something so that she also has access to it

They suggested that I redownload and reinstall the software from my wife's account. I clarified to say that I wanted to be able to use the software from any account. They reiterated that this was the right thing to do. They are wrong. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assumptions

- You are using MacOS X Lion. (I haven't tested on other versions of MacOS X)
- You've installed WiTopia's VPN client and have gotten it to work from your user account.
- You have another user account on your system that you want WiTopia to work from.
- You are familiar with using Terminal and relatively comfortable using the command line.
- Your login has administrative privileges (if not, you can enable them in System Preferences).
- The term `targetaccount` in the following steps is used as a placeholder for whatever account you're trying to enable to use the WiTopia VPN service. You need to replace it with the actual name of the account you're trying to enable.

#### Steps

1. **Login to your user account.**
2. **Open Terminal.app.** This can be found in the `/Applications` folder.
3. **Become root.** Type in `sudo -s`. The password is your login password.
4. **Archive the directory you will be replacing.** If the directory `~targetaccount/Library/Application Support/WiTopia` already exists, copy it to a safe place in case this process doesn't work; you can copy it back if something bad happens. If this directory doesn't exist then no worries.
5. **Copy the WiTopia Application Support directory to the user account where WiTopia isn't working.** Use the following command: `cp -R ~/Library/Application Support/WiTopia ~targetaccount/Library/Application Support/WiTopia`.
6. **Change the permissions on the `WiTopia` directory.** `cd ~targetaccount/Library/Application Support` Then `chown -R targetaccount WiTopia`.
7. **Login to your target account and test WiTopia.**

#### Notes on WiTopia

I have always had good customer support from WiTopia and their VPN service seems pretty decent *Sidenote:* It's hard to compare since I haven't used any other VPN service and sometimes when the throughput is bad it's difficult to tell whether it's the network (I live in China) or WiTopia who is at fault. I would definitely recommend WiTopia but it can be frustrating sometimes if you're pretty tech-savvy; they're customer support is really designed for the layman.